# can't set JAVA_HOME with actual JDK version

Tags: java, linux, path, jvm, java-11

I'm using Kali Linux OS, I have JDK version 18.0.1.1, in terminal:
**<$ java --version>** Output:

```
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true
java 18.0.1.1 2022-04-22
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 18.0.1.1+2-6)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 18.0.1.1+2-6, mixed mode, sharing)
```

and **<$ javac --version>** Output is:

```
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true
javac 18.0.1.1
```

Now te problem: when I use **<$ echo $JAVA_HOME>**  the output is:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
```

This is the text that I have inside **/etc/environment** :

```
# START KALI-DEFAULTS CONFIG
# Everything from here and until STOP KALI-DEFAULTS CONFIG
# was installed by the kali-defaults package, and it will
# be removed if ever the kali-defaults package is removed.
# If you want to disable a line, please do NOT remove it,
# as it would be added back when kali-defaults is upgraded.
# Instead, comment the line out, and your change will be
# preserved across upgrades.
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
COMMAND_NOT_FOUND_INSTALL_PROMPT=1
POWERSHELL_UPDATECHECK=Off
POWERSHELL_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT=1
DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT=1
# STOP KALI-DEFAULTS CONFIG
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-18"
```

THanks for help!

Comment: When you type `java --version` or `javac --version`, the commands will be resolved like any other program, through the `PATH` variable for most shells. The value of the `JAVA_HOME` variable has no relevance to Java’s standard launch mechanism at all.

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't compile any java class, but there was an error and the /etc/profile path has the version of JDK11, thanks anyways !